# Add leading zeros in mvc gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

i have a gridview in mvc and it works well. But i want my int column to have leading zeros.

For example: 1 becomes 01 and 10 becomes 10

Below is my sample code:

```html
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(foo => foo.srfId).Titled("SRF NO").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
    })
```

Comment: here srfId is string or int?

Comment: srfId is an int... I have an idea of formatting it into string then padleft but idk how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two possible approaches one when you add new properties in your model itself with just `getter` and add column for that property.

```
class MyModel
{
   ...
   ...
   public int srfId { get; set;}
   ...
   ...
   public string SrfIdFormatted
   {
     get { srfId.ToString("00"); }
   }
   ...
}
```

then in your view you can do something -

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(foo => foo.SrfIdFormatted).Titled("SRF ID");
})
```

and second one is -- I remember we have `Format` method on `column` also.  But I am not sure, try this as well, if it works for you.

```
columns.Add(c => c.SrfId).Format("{0:00}").Titled("SRF ID");
```